# Format USB thumb drive

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I got the following drive:

```
Device Identifier:        disk1
Device Node:              /dev/disk1
Part of Whole:            disk1
Device / Media Name:      SanDisk Firebird Media

Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

File System:              None

Content (IOContent):      None
OS Can Be Installed:      No
Media Type:               Generic
Protocol:                 USB
SMART Status:             Not Supported

Total Size:               67.1 MB (67108864 Bytes) (exactly 131072 512-Byte-Units)
Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

Read-Only Media:          No
Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
Ejectable:                Yes
```

How do I add a file system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 USBDRIVE MBRFormat /dev/disk1
```

...where `USBDRIVE` is the desired volume name. Apparently, it must be all caps.

Comment: getting unknown partition name

Comment: waiting for disks to reappear
:-)
cheers

Comment: How long does this normally take still waiting on them reappearing ?

Comment: Dunno. You sure the drive is okay? Judging from its size, it must be very old.

Comment: it is ! no its getting stuck at 50% any ideas ?

Comment: shall i just buy a new one !!! lol

Comment: Apparently there are some Sandisk drives somehow “reverting” to this state, interesting. If it’s still warranty-covered, you might want to try that. Otherwise, just get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Disk Utility (Applications/ Disk Utility) and pressing the disk. Select erase after you are sure you have backed up your files. Choose a file system (default is Mac OSX Extended Journaled).